# Does a @Published property in an ObservableObject update all of it's views?

Tags: swiftui

If I have a class:

**VehicleListViewModel**

```
class VehicleListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var CarCategoryViewModel = VehicleCategoryViewModel()
    @Published var VanCategoryViewModel = VehicleCategoryViewModel()
    @Published var BicycleCategoryViewModel = VehicleCategoryViewModel()
    ...
}
```

**VehicleCategoryViewModel**

```
class VehicleCategoryViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var VehicleCellViewModels = [VehicleCellViewModel]()
}
```

**VehicleCellViewModel**

```
class VehicleCellViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {

    var id = UUID().uuidString
    @Published var vehicle: Vehicle
    @Published var backgroundColor = ""

}
```

**Vehicle**

```
struct Vehicle: Identifiable, Decodable, Encodable {

    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var name: String
    var userHas: Bool

 }
```

and several views which use each of those three view models, created in a parent view:

**ContentView**

```
 @ObservedObject var vehicleListVM = VehicleListViewModel()

ScrollView {
    VehicleCategoryView(VehicleCategoryVM: $vehicleListVM.CarCategoryViewModel)
    VehicleCategoryView(VehicleCategoryVM: $vehicleListVM.VanCategoryViewModel)
    VehicleCategoryView(VehicleCategoryVM: $vehicleListVM.BicycleCategoryViewModel)
 ...
}
```

**VehicleCategoryView**

```
@Binding var VehicleCategoryVM : VehicleCategoryViewModel
...
```

If a change is made to one of the bindings in **VehicleCategoryView** this should propagate to **VehicleListViewModel** and cause the **@ObservedObject var vehicleListVM** to refresh the view in ScrollView that was changed. But, would a change to lets say CarCategoryViewModel cause a refresh of all three views inside ScrollView?

If so, how could I prevent this so that each data is independent and doesn't cause refreshes to the others.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are models (like VehicleCategoryViewModel) struct types or also ObservableObject?

Comment: @Asperi I've updated the question with all classes/structs

Answer (score 0):

You don't need binding in this case, just pass sub-model by reference

```
ScrollView {
    VehicleCategoryView(VehicleCategoryVM: vehicleListVM.CarCategoryViewModel)
    // .. other code
```

and use inside

```
@ObservedObject var VehicleCategoryVM : VehicleCategoryViewModel
```

in this case parent view will be rebuilt only if sub-model object will be recreated, and not if just internal properties changed, but corresponding subview will be updated.